# Where do I place common jQuery code in Angular.js Controllers

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular.js and jQuery together on a project.  I had a problem where the jQuery code inside my document ready was being fired before the page has completely loaded thus some things weren't working correctly.  I moved my jQuery code into my Angular.js controller by doing

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //jQuery code
})
```

This fixed the problem however what do I do if I want the same jQuery code to be used by two controllers.  I don't want to duplicate the code so is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Create a shared service, or a directive (which should be used for DOM manipulation) and inject the above into both your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared service, or a directive (which should be used for DOM manipulation) and inject the above into both your controllers.